# How to fix SVR plot in Python sklearn

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am trying to fit an SVR model to my dataset and view the plot using Sklearn in Python.

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
#Load Data
X_train_Occ = pd.DataFrame(X_train['occupancy'])
Y_train_Occ = Y_train
#Rescale
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_Y = StandardScaler()
X_train_Occ_scaled = sc_X.fit_transform(X_train_Occ)
Y_train_Occ_scaled = sc_Y.fit_transform(Y_train_Occ.reshape(-1, 1))

regressor = SVR(kernel ='rbf')
regressor.fit(X_train_Occ_scaled, Y_train_Occ_scaled)
```

I load my data into X and Y dataframes and scale them. 
see the plot below:

[image]

I then get the following output:

```
SVR(C=1.0, cache_size=200, coef0=0.0, degree=3, epsilon=0.1, gamma='auto', kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
```

Then I try to show the results of the regression with this:

```
plt.scatter(X_train_Occ_scaled, Y_train_Occ_scaled, color = 'red')
plt.plot(X_train_Occ_scaled, regressor.predict(X_train_Occ_scaled), color = 'blue')
plt.title('Occupancy vs Flow (SVR)')
plt.xlabel('Occupancy')
plt.ylabel('Flow')
plt.show()
```

Which gives the following plot:

[image]

Has the model over-fitted to the data? or is there something wrong with the code?

I am following the code from here:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_svm_regression.html

I am trying to draw the line of best fit with the model, not a line from each point.

Comment: What kind of plot did you expect? What you see is what you get when using ```plt.plot()``` with inputs non conform with the assumptions. Read matplotlib's docs on what plot really does (it plots lines between neighbors in your inputs; basically). Maybe you want ```plt.scatter()``` or something else. Recommendation: remove one tag (e.g. non-linear reg) and replace it with *matplotlib* (one of the more important tags for this question).

Comment: Thanks I have updated my question. @sascha

Comment: (Super-short look at the reference-code:) The reason your code fails and the referenced does not is that their x is sorted. This will all get very clear and simple after reading what matplotlib's plotting-functions do! Use numpy's argsort to sort x and y in parallel and plot again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As previously answered, the solution was to sort the data first by the independent variable, then fit the data to the model and predict the outcome.

[image]

Comment: How did you sort the data? I had the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `plt.plot` since all the data are randomly ordered. use `plt.scatter` or rank the data from min to max first